# Как передать параметр в метод

Tags: c#, winforms, передача-параметров

Вопрос следующий. У нас есть метод, который открывает окно оплаты, первым аргументом мы передаем сумму, а вторым нужно передать источник оплаты. Можно было бы передать просто строку. Но как я понимаю, правильно было бы передать параметр.

```
 public partial class Pay : Form
    {
        private Context Context = new Context();

        public Pay()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public static DialogResult Open(decimal Amount, PaySource Source)
        {
            var form = new Pay();
            form.ShowDialog();

            return form.DialogResult;
        }
    }

    public struct PaySource
    {

    }
```

Как мне правильно сделать так, что бы  я мог сделать так.

```
Pay.Open(666, PaySource.FromWorkShop)
```

Или

```
Pay.Open(666, PaySource.FromKassa)
```

То есть это должно быть что то вроде

```
System.Drawing.Color.Red
```

Comment: [enum](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/enum)

Comment: У вас источники оплаты фиксированные? Вы если их в коде зашьёте, то новые источники нельзя будет добавить без изменений в коде. Если это ваш случай, то энумы.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public enum PaySource
{
  FromWorkShop,
  FromKassa
}
public Pay()
{
   InitializeComponent();
}

public static DialogResult Open(decimal Amount, PaySource Source)
{
     if(Source.FromWorkShop)
     {
         // Что то делаете
     }
     elseif(Source.FromKassa)
     {
         // Что то делаете 
     }
     var form = new Pay();
     form.ShowDialog();
     return form.DialogResult;
}
```

Использование: `Open(100, PaySource.FromWorkShop);`

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]